Inheritance from PathSegment class
I don't know how to write class which gona inherit from PathSegment class.
No matter how many parameters is in constructor This code give me error CS1729
public class BindableLineSegment : PathSegment
{
    public BindableLineSegment()
    {

    }

    protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

}


See the Online Documentation:

Notes to Implementers
Although this class is abstract, it is not publicly extensible.


You can also look at the Reference Source:
PathSegment only has an internal constructor, which means you can not derive from it.

Besides that, it is unclear what a "BindableLineSegment" is supposed to be. The Point property of a LineSegment is already bindable, because it is a dependency property.

Ok, Thanks for info.
